# Sequential Uni executions

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

I have a list of elements

> List <Element> elements.

For each of those elements i want to call an async method that return an Uni

> ```
> private Uni<String> asyncMetthod(Element element) {
>    ....
> }
> ```

The problem is that i want to call those methods sequentially : 
I call the method with the first element in the list, on result received i call the same method with the second element and so on ... 
If one fail i still want to continue

I suspect that i need to use a Multi with Multi.createFrom().iterable but i have no clue what do do next.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```java
var multi = Multi.createFrom().iterable(elements)
   .onItem().transformToUniAndConcatenate(element -> {
        return asyncMethod(element)
           .onFailure().continueWith(fallback_when_failing);
    });
```